# CSS content and position in IE8

Tags: css

Good morning ,

I am currently working on a sharepoint site and i am required to create some sort of an organization chart. The chart will go in a content editor webpart whish is straight forward to me. Found a sample online and modified it to fit my needs. http://jsfiddle.net/hp5ksgfh/6/
The problem i am having is with IE8 (default browser for the site).

The code below draws the chart perfectly in IE9+ and fails on IE8:

```
     <style type="text/css">
        .tree
        {
            width: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        .tree ul
        {
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-left: 0;
            position: relative;
        }
        .tree li
        {
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            list-style-type: none;
            position: relative;
            padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        }
        /*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/
        .tree li::before, .tree li::after
        {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 50%;
            border-top: 1px solid #e1793f;
            width: 50%;
            height: 20px;
        }
        .tree li:after
        {
            right: auto;
            left: 50%;
            border-left: 1px solid #e1793f;
        }
        /*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
        .tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before
        {
            display: none;
        }
        /*Remove space from the top of single children*/
        .tree li:only-child
        {
            padding-top: 0;
        }
        /*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
        .tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after
        {
            border: 0 none;
        }
        /*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
        .tree li:last-child::before
        {
            border-right: 1px solid #e1793f;
            border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
            -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
        }
        .tree li:first-child::after
        {
            border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
        }
        /*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
        .tree ul ul::before
        {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 50%;
            border-left: 1px solid #e1793f;
            width: 0;
            height: 20px;
            margin-left: -1px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        /*This will draw the links in an organigram format*/
        .tree li a
        {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #666;
            font-family: calibri, verdana, tahoma;
            font-size: 11px;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            transition: all 0.5s;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        }
        /*Time for some hover effects*/
        /*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
        .tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover + ul li a
        {
            background: #c8e4f8;
            color: #000;
            border: 1px solid #0771bd;
        }
        /*Connector styles on hover*/
        .tree li a:hover + ul li::after, .tree li a:hover + ul li::before, .tree li a:hover + ul::before, .tree li a:hover + ul ul::before
        {
            border-color: #94a0b4;
        }
        li a.just-line
        {
            display: none;
        }
        a.just-line + ul
        {
            padding-top: 74px;
        }
        a.just-line + ul:before
        {
            height: 74px;
        }

        /*images and text inside a to be positioned left and right */
        a.tip img
        {
            float: left;
            font-family: Veranda;
        }
        a.tip h3
        {
            float: right;
        }
        /*Having the a position relative will help in showing Tooltip next to its element*/
        a.tip
        {
            padding: 0;
            position: relative;
        }
        /* Tooltip section */
        a.tip span
        {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 290px;
            width: 525px;
            padding: 5px;
            z-index: 100;
            background: #ffffcc;
            color: Black;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
        /*Tooltip pointer*/
        a.tip span:before
        {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            position: absolute;
            border-top: 8px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
            border-right: 8px solid Black;
            left: -8px;
            top: 7px;
        }
        /*Tooltip hidden by default*/
        a:hover.tip span
        {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="tree">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="tip" href="#">
                <img src="pics/face.JPG" alt="" />
                <h3>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    Mark Sprenger
                    <br />
                    Chief Operations Management</h3>
                <span>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <strong>Name:</strong> someone someone
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <strong>Contact:</strong>0000
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <strong>Position:</strong> Chief Geographic Information Systems
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <strong>Email address:</strong> someone@someone
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <hr />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" colspan="2">
                                    <strong>Qualifications &amp; Background: </strong>Jrandom text goes here
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="tip" href="#">
                        <img src="pics/face.JPG" alt="" />
                        <h3>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            Mark Sprenger1
                            <br />
                            Chief Operations Management</h3>
                        <span>
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <strong>Name:</strong> someone someone
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <strong>Contact:</strong>0000
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <strong>Position:</strong> Chief Geographic Information Systems
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <strong>Email address:</strong> someone@someone
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <hr />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" colspan="2">
                                            <strong>Qualifications &amp; Background: </strong>random text goes here
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="tip" href="#">
                                <img src="pics/face.JPG" alt="" />
                                <h3>
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    Mark Sprenger2
                                    <br />
                                    Chief Operations Management</h3>
                                <span>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <strong>Name:</strong> someone someone
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <strong>Contact:</strong>0000
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <strong>Position:</strong> Chief Geographic Information Systems
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <strong>Email address:</strong> someone@someone
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <hr />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left" colspan="2">
                                                    <strong>Qualifications &amp; Background: </strong>random text goes here
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </span></a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a class="tip" href="#">
                                        <img src="pics/face.JPG" alt="" />
                                        <h3>
                                            <br />
                                            <br />
                                            Mark Sprenger3
                                            <br />
                                            Chief Operations Management</h3>
                                        <span>
                                            <table>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            <strong>Name:</strong> someone someone
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            <strong>Contact:</strong>0000
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            <strong>Position:</strong> Chief Geographic Information Systems
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            <strong>Email address:</strong> someone@someone
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2">
                                                            <hr />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left" colspan="2">
                                                            <strong>Qualifications &amp; Background: </strong>Jrandom text goes here
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </span></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="tip" href="#">
                                        <img src="pics/face.JPG" alt="" />
                                        <h3>
                                            <br />
                                            <br />
                                            Mark Sprenger4
                                            <br />
                                            Chief Operations Management</h3>
                                        <span>
                                            <table>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            <strong>Name:</strong> someone someone
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            <strong>Contact:</strong>0000
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            <strong>Position:</strong> Chief Geographic Information Systems
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            <strong>Email address:</strong> someone@someone
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2">
                                                            <hr />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left" colspan="2">
                                                            <strong>Qualifications &amp; Background: </strong>random text goes here
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </span></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="tip" href="#">
                                        <img src="pics/face.JPG" alt="" />
                                        <h3>
                                            <br />
                                            <br />
                                            Mark Sprenger5
                                            <br />
                                            Chief Operations Management</h3>
                                        <span>
                                            <table>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            <strong>Name:</strong> someone someone
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            <strong>Contact:</strong>0000
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            <strong>Position:</strong> Chief Geographic Information Systems
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            <strong>Email address:</strong> someone@someone
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2">
                                                            <hr />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left" colspan="2">
                                                            <strong>Qualifications &amp; Background: </strong>Jrandom text goes here
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

The code fails when i try to draw the connectors for example here:
  /*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/
        .tree li::before, .tree li::after
        {
            content: ''; /* headache*/
            position: absolute; /* headache*/
            top: 0;
            right: 50%;
            border-top: 1px solid #e1793f;
            width: 50%;
            height: 20px;
        }
```

I would appreciate if you can assist with a hack or a workaround so that it works in IE8+.
Many thanks

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) IE8 could only work with the single-colon notation of `:before` and `:after`.

Comment: you only need to support ie11 and edge in 2018 of the microsoft browsers http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-version-market-share